# Did WWII fighters have inverted airfoils for horizontal stabilizers?

Tags: aerodynamics, stability, airfoil, horizontal-stabilizer, tail-dragger

Like would for example the P-47 most likely have symmetric, normal or inverted airfoil as horz. tail?

Is my analysis correct?:

It has a CG at 25-32% MAC according to manual. Since AC on wings is usually located around 25% MAC it safe to assume the CG is aft of AC. Since the setup is that way, it would be normal to have horizontal tail producing positive lift.

Also; did typical WWII planes have inverted airfoils as horizontal stabilizers?

What about general aviation planes today?

Comment: The P-51 used a NACA 6-Series airfoil which was not symmetric

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Longitudinal Stability (Pitching)](http://avstop.com/ac/flighttrainghandbook/longitudinalstability.html) chapter in the FAA Pilot's Handbook, two things stand out to me:

#### One:

[image]

Regardless of the airfoil shape, nose-heavy airplanes like WWII fighters will almost always have downforce on the horizontal stabilizer.

Even if the airfoil is not inverted, it will be attached at a negative angle of attack.

> Compensation for this nose heaviness is provided by setting the horizontal stabilizer at a slight negative angle of attack.

Cutaway drawings for the P-47 seem to suggest they're not inverted, example:

[image]
([Source](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/6b/60/d6/6b60d6628d3ae6e724408108197c2284.jpg))

#### Two:

Unless it's a T-tail, the propwash combined with the downwash results in downforce on the horizontal stabilizer.

[image]
([Source](http://learntoflyblog.com/page/8/))

---

P.S. Do not rush to accept, wait for votes or wait for our resident aerodynamicists to answer.